# Error while Importing pyspark ETL module and running as child process using pything subprocess

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to call a list of pyspark modules dynamically from one main.py python script, using Import module and subprocess. The child modules I'm trying to call does not return anything, it just does its ETL operation. I want my main.py program to wait until the child process completes. In the code below, everytime I'm trying to call the child process, I end up with the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable". One other problem is, after initiating the subprocess.Popen, I thought the flow will keep continuing in the main.py to next line, until it hits the j1.wait(),  but the immediate print statment (print("etl_01_job is running") is not executing, Am I missing anything?

I googled and tried a lot of other ways, but nothing is working. can anyone shed some light on what am I doing wrong? Once I'm able to successfully call the child process, I have to add few other conditions based on the return code of the child proces. But at this point, I want to fix this issue. Thanks

main.py

```
import json
import importlib
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession


def main():
    with open('C:/Pyspark/test/config/config.json', 'r') as config_file:
        config = json.load(config_file)

    spark = SparkSession.builder\
        .appName(config.get("app_name"))\
        .getOrCreate()

    job_module1 = importlib.import_module("etl_01_job")
    print("main calling time :", datetime.now())
    j1 = subprocess.Popen(job_module1.run_etl_01_job(spark, config))
    print("etl_01_job is running")
    j1.wait() #I'm expecting the main.py to wait until child process finishes
    print("etl_01_job finished")

    job_module2 = importlib.import_module("etl_02_job")
    j2 = subprocess.Popen(job_module2.run_etl_02_job(spark, config))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Child pyspark job:etl_01_job.py : Not the original code, just a sample script

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys

def etl_01_job(spark, config):
    print("I'm in 01etljob")
    print(config)
    print(config.get("app_name"))
    time.sleep(10)
    print("etljob 1 ending time :", datetime.now())
def run_etl_01_job(spark, config):
    etl_01_job(spark, config)
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/py_spark/src/main.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/py_spark/src/main.py", line 38, in main
    p1 = subprocess.run(job_module1.run_etl_01_job(spark, config))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1247, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 549, in list2cmdline
    for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `subprocess.Popen(job_module1.run_etl_01_job(spark, config))` is not a way to create a subprocess that is running `job_module1.run_etl_01_job` with arguments `(spark, config))`. What you are doing here is just running `job_module1.run_etl_01_job(spark, config)` locally (not in a different process) which returns `None`, then calling `subprocess.Popen(None)` which in turn gives you the error you posted.

What you probably meant to do is to use `multiprocessing` python module as in

```
from multiprocessing import Process

p1 = Process(target=job_module1.run_etl_01_job, args=(spark, config))
p2 = Process(target=job_module2.run_etl_02_job, args=(spark, config))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

That said I don't think it's going to work since arguments to `multiprocessing` are pickled and I don't think SparkSession object will survive pickling/unpickling. You might also want to try use `threading` module here instead or even more convenient `concurrent.futures` module like so:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as e:
  future1 = e.submit(job_module1.run_etl_01_job, spark, config)
  future2 = e.submit(job_module2.run_etl_02_job, spark, config)
  result1 = future1.result()
  result2 = future2.result()
```

This will run in one process and use multiple, but the actual Spark jobs will run in parallel (Spark remote execution releases Python's GIL similar to IO operations, though some steps might need it e.g. when final result in merged at Spark driver).

Comment: I reffered this https://levelup.gitconnected.com/master-the-concurrency-in-python-cedd070a913c  and this https://www.nurmatova.com/subprocesses-and-multithreading.html, learnt subprocess runs child process with its own memory, That is what I wanted, In some cases, I have to run child process sequentially and in others parallely with it's own memory.  If I'm not wrong multiprocessing uses the same parent process memory, isn't it?  In my scripit, whether running the process locally is a problem ? or not returning anything? I tried returning some dummy value, even then I'm getting the same error

Comment: You are wrong - multiprocessing is running child process with its own memory same way as subprocess does. They are similar in that sense. But subprocess is for running  executables with arguments (any executable - like java or gcc or rsync) while multiprocessing is to spawn specifically new python process(es) to run python callables passed to it with `pickle` serialization with arguments also passed to it with `pickle` serialization.

Comment: When you use expression `subprocess.Popen(my_function(my_argument))` for Python it doesn't look different from `any_other_callable(my_function(my_argument))` - it will locally compute `my_function(my_argument)` and try to pass it to the `any_other_callable`. In your case `any_other_callable` is `subprocess.Popen` and you pass it `None` after it was returned as a result of locally running `job_module1.run_etl_01_job(spark, config)`.

Comment: If you have situation where you have function `my_function` and argument `my_argument` and want to spawn a new python process that would apply `my_function` to `my_argument` and give you back the result - that is exactly what `multiprocessing` is for.

Comment: Python's `threading` module looks similar to `multiprocessing` in terms of interface, but it is the one that actually creates new threads in the python process rather than new python processes. So if you use `threading` - that's the one that using same parent process memory. The thing is you might have better luck using that since it doesn't need to serialize/deserialize your Spark session.

Comment: By the way, what is the goal you're trying to achieve by running these in different processes?

Comment: I'm trying to build a orchestration script to run a list of pyspark jobs both sequentially and in some cases parallely. By creating the spark , hive session  from the main script and passing them with the config parameters from the main script.

Comment: You should either create a new (separate) Spark session inside any new process you create or - which seems a better for your case - use threading instead - simplest way would be through concurrent.futures module. If you're concerned that with multiple threads the jobs will not run in parallel (because of Python's GIL, then your concern is not applied here - the jobs will run in parallel on Spark).

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of how to run parallel Spark jobs using `concurrent.futures` module - it is same process, but Spark execution will happen in parallel.

Comment: I did some tests, The concurrent.futures is able to run the pyspark modules in parallel. but as you said when tried to use 'Process', I'm not able to pass the sparkcontext as a argument, I'm getting an exception "Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable...", What to do If I have to run pyspark modules one after the other (sequentially) on success on each module, now that subprocess and process each have some problems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231652/discussion-between-alexander-pivovarov-and-user7343922).